# Android Animation Bouncing Effect

Tags: android, animation, surfaceview

I have a image with dice inside RelativeLayout. What i want is to make it bounce inside the Layout. What i tried is that when the imageView crossed the bottom or top then change its current animation direction and play them. For x movement i did the same. But when i play together things are not working as i want. Below is my code :

```
package com.example.aaa111.androidrnd;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class AnimationTest extends AppCompatActivity {

private ObjectAnimator diceOneAnim;
private ObjectAnimator diceTwoAnim;
private ObjectAnimator diceOneTrAnim;
private ImageView diceOneImage;
private ImageView diceTwoImage;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
private boolean animSet;
private Rect r1;
private Rect r2;
private int currX = 0;
private int currY = 0;
private int toX = 2500;
private int toY = 2000;

private boolean newAnim = false;
private Rect rootRect;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation_test);

    animSet = false;
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    diceOneImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.diceOneImage);
    diceTwoImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.diceTwoImage);

    relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {
            relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    int[] l = new int[2];

    relativeLayout.getLocationOnScreen(l);

    rootRect = new Rect(l[0], l[1], l[0] + relativeLayout.getWidth(), l[1] + relativeLayout.getHeight());

    System.out.println("relativeLayout width  : " + relativeLayout.getWidth());
    System.out.println("relativeLayout height : " + relativeLayout.getHeight());

    makeNewAnim();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_animation_test, menu);
    return true;
}

private void makeNewAnim()
{
    final AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();

    ValueAnimator y = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(diceOneImage,"translationY",currY, toY);

    ValueAnimator x = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(diceOneImage, "translationX", currX, toX);

    ValueAnimator rotate =  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(diceOneImage,"rotation",0, 360);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    rotate.setDuration(2000);

    x.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
        {
            final int[] l = new int[2];

            l[0] = (int) diceOneImage.getX();
            l[1] = (int) diceOneImage.getY();

            System.out.println("l[0] : " + l[0]);
            System.out.println("l[1] : " + l[1]);

            Rect rect = new Rect(l[0], l[1], l[0] + diceOneImage.getWidth(), l[1] + diceOneImage.getHeight());

            float rx = relativeLayout.getX();
            float rw = relativeLayout.getWidth();

            if (rect.right > relativeLayout.getX() + relativeLayout.getWidth()) {
                final float offset = l[0] - diceOneImage.getWidth() - (rect.right - (relativeLayout.getX() + relativeLayout.getWidth()));

                animSetXY.cancel();
                ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(diceOneImage, "translationX", l[0], l[0] - diceOneImage.getWidth() - (rect.right - (relativeLayout.getX() + relativeLayout.getWidth())));
                animator.setDuration(5);
                animator.start();

                animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                    {
                        currY = l[1];

                        currX = (int) offset;

                        toX = toX * (-1);

                        makeNewAnim();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation)
                    {

                    }
                });


                return;
            }

            if (rect.left < relativeLayout.getLeft())
            {

                animSetXY.cancel();
                ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(diceOneImage, "translationX", l[0], l[0] + 20);
                animator.setDuration(5);
                animator.start();

                animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                    {
                        currY = l[1];

                        currX = l[0] + 20;

                        toX = toX * (-1);

                        makeNewAnim();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation)
                    {

                    }
                });

                return;
            }
        }
    });

    y.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
        {
            final int[] l = new int[2];

            l[0] = (int) diceOneImage.getX();
            l[1] = (int) diceOneImage.getY();//getRelativeTop(diceOneImage);

            System.out.println("l[0] : " + l[0]);
            System.out.println("l[1] : " + l[1]);

            Rect rect = new Rect(l[0], l[1], l[0] + diceOneImage.getWidth(), l[1] + diceOneImage.getHeight());

            if (rect.bottom > relativeLayout.getY() + relativeLayout.getHeight())
            {
                animSetXY.cancel();
                ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(diceOneImage, "translationY", l[1], l[1] - 20);
                animator.setDuration(2);
                animator.start();

                animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                    {
                        currY = l[1] - 20;

                        toY = -1 * toY;

                        //currX = (int) diceOneImage.getX();

                        //toX = toX * (-1);

                        makeNewAnim();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation)
                    {

                    }
                });


                return;
            }

            if (rect.top < relativeLayout.getTop())
            {
                animSetXY.cancel();
                ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(diceOneImage, "translationY", l[1], l[1] + 20);
                animator.setDuration(2);
                animator.start();

                animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                    {
                        currY = l[1] + 20;

                        toY = -1 * toY;

                        //currX = (int) diceOneImage.getX();

                        //toX = toX * (-1);

                        makeNewAnim();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation)
                    {

                    }
                });

                return;
            }
        }
    });

    animSetXY.playTogether(rotate, x,y);
    animSetXY.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animSetXY.setDuration(2000);
    animSetXY.start();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}   
  }
```

I have looked into surfaceview option to achieve this effect and i am managing to achieve it very well inside that. But problem is i have to play a video ad after some time of the bounce ends (Much like omni swipe) and my surfaceview gets hanged after the ad ends. Inside logcat i gets concurrent exception. So i choose to go with this option instead. By the way i am using HeyZap SDK for video ad.